# How to get input file value instead of using FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Does someone know how to get `<input type="file">` value to pass through an Ajax call?

Instead of:

```
// more...

function uploadFile(event) {
        var file = event.target.files;
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        var data = new FormData();

        $.each(
            file,
            function(key, value) {
                data.append(key, value);
            }
        );

        $.ajax({
            url: 'site/upload',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
// more...
```

The `uploadFile()` is called on change of the input file.
The problem with using **FormData** object is that it's not supported in IE 10-.

Comment: you can simply send() the form or file, but a lot of folks don't know that...

Comment: i thought IE9 supports ajax2...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to get input file value instead of using FormData

You can't.

Without `FormData`, your only options are Flash and posting to an iframe.

I suggest using FormData if it is currently available, else just submit it to an iframe or cause a full page postback.

Or, you can use one of the many plugins that already do this for you.

Comment: what about FileReader(), does that not count? it should: http://caniuse.com/filereader

Comment: It also isn't supported IE<10, so that doesn't help. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: Also, FileReader is not used to upload files, only to read them client-side, which is not necessary if you simply intend to upload a selected file.

Comment: well, technically, if you could read the file, you could send it's data:uri to the server as text, so it could help, if it were even available(but it's not)